# Calculate Youden's index for random forest using ROCR package?

Tags: r

I am creating a random forest model and then using the `ROCR` package to create a ROC plot. Im trying to calculate Youden's index and I was wondering if Im doing it correctly. Youden's index is defined as the sensitivity + specificity - 1.

For example, the code below creates some data and a random forest model. Im then using the  `prediction` function from the `ROCR` package to get sensitivity and specificity values. Im then taking the mean of the values and subtracting 1, like so:

```
library(ROCR)
library(randomForest)
# create some data
data(iris)
iris2 = iris[51:150,]
iris2$Species = as.numeric(iris2$Species)

# create random forest
rf <- randomForest::randomForest(Species~.,, data = iris2)

# use the predicitons from ROCR
pred <- ROCR::prediction(rf$predicted, iris2$Species)

# get youdens index
sens <- performance(pred, measure = "sens")@y.values[[1]]
spec <- performance(pred, measure = "spec")@y.values[[1]]
youden <- mean(sens) + mean(spec) - 1

> youden
[1] 0.48
```

Using this method, I get a value of 0.48. However, while doing research online, I saw someone calculate Youden's index using the cutoffs generated by `ROCR` package, like so:

```
sens <- performance(pred, measure = "sens")@y.values[[1]]
spec <- performance(pred, measure = "spec")@y.values[[1]]
ss <- sens + spec
Yindex <- which.max(ss)

cutoffs   <- performance(pred, measure = "sens")@x.values[[1]]
youdenVal <- cutoffs[Yindex]
> youdenVal
     134 
2.389319
```

However, this gives a value of 2.4... I was wondering is my original method correct for calculating Youden's index... and can someone explain the logic behind the second method (or is the second method just incorrect)?